# Cannot use UI of Db2 on Cloud Lite plan

Tags: db2

I have a Db2 on Cloud (Lite plan) instance, Db2-n3, that was working OK until a few days ago, and I am trying to use for testing with IBM App Connect on IBM Cloud.

I now cannot access the Db2 UI.  When I click "Goto UI", the UI opens with only the error message

```
HWCBAS0055E: Failed to check for the authorization information from the request.
```

...and trying to view Data shows the error:

```
HWCCON0030E: Failed to get connection profile crn:v1:bluemix:public:dashdb-for-transactions:eu-gb:a/5a9a0a1ff3f4b8bddb072055bfc1a2f6:1bd1d12d-3a54-4e57-b6f5-6250e9bb00e9::.
```

I also cannot work with data in Db2 nor connect to the instance from within IBM App Connect (despite having created new Db2 credentials before these problems started)

Can someone help me recover use of the Db2 on Lite instance?

Comment: I managed to create a new Db2 on Cloud instance, Db2-6t, and was able to load data to a new table, but shortly after could not use the Db2 UI.  When I try to look at the table, it fails with:

"Exceeded maximum limit of 5 connections. Connection refused SQLCODE=-438, SQLSTATE=42502"

This might be a different error to what is happening with Db2-n3, but indicates something wrong with the Db2 UI access.

Comment: Do you have something connected to the database? The Lite plan is VERY limited and multi-tenant. It works to create some tables and try out SQL statements, but it is not for any connection or performance tests.

Comment: This seems more of a support question towards IBM, not programming-related.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be addressed to the vendor technical support.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced the same issue, and it was caused by my ID being suspended as a result of numerous attempts to connect with the incorrect PWD. I don't know how it happened, but the solution for me was to contact IBM Cloud and request that they unluck the DB user id.